# Service is failing with no exception thrown

Tags: service, unhandled-exception

I am somewhat new at developing in the VS C# environment and have come across the following issue. I have developed a C# service (BrassSS) that interfaces to an MS Access database and has been running since February 2018. The service is meant to perform a nightly backup at 4:00am, send reminder emails at 7 am, and status emails at 10,2, and 6 daily. This has all been running fine for years until about a week ago when a customer calls me that reminder emails were not working. BrassSS keeps a log which I checked and noticed that the service is now dying just a few milliseconds later when I attempt to open the database to send reminder emails at 7:00am. This had never happened so I have been trying to scour the internet with my limited knowledge and struggling with this. Note that I have a 'mirror' image of the service that I run as a console app (BrassConsoleApp), which also fails at the same location. I finally made it to the Event Viewer (two log entries shown below) and it would seem that an unhandled exception is occurring.

I don't know if this helps, and may only add to the confusion, but in the last month I have switched MS Access from 2007 to 2016. Having said that, note that at 4:00am, when the backup kicks in, the exact same code you see below to open the database, runs with no issue.

So at 7:00am, the timer elapses and I need to open the database, here is my code:

```
class DBif
{
    const string cstClassName = "DBif";

    private OleDbConnection conDB;
    private string strPathToBEFile;

    public bool openDB(string strFullPathToDB) {
        // Connects to the DB 
        this.strPathToBEFile = strFullPathToDB;
        try {
            if (this.conDB != null) {
                this.conDB.Close();
            }
            Logs.addEvent("Info", cstClassName, "openDB", "Attempt to Open DB: " + strPathToBEFile);  //debug

            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" + strPathToBEFile + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + "----------" + ";";
            Logs.addEvent("Info", cstClassName, "openDB", "Connection string: " + strPathToBEFile);  //debug

            this.conDB = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            Logs.addEvent("Info", cstClassName, "openDB", "conDB successfull " + strPathToBEFile);  //debug

            this.conDB.Open(); ***<---- I place a breakpoint here, step over it, and the app FAILS WITH NO EXCEPTION***
            Logs.addEvent("Info", cstClassName, "openDB", "DB Opened successfully: " + strPathToBEFile);  //debug

            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logs.addEvent("CRITICAL", cstClassName, "openConnection", "Error trying to Open database: " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

.....
}

I am hoping that some expert can shed some light into this and help me get to the root cause.

This is the Event Viewer log entry showing an ERROR when the app fails;

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          2021-Jun-10 4:30:01 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Dell5759
Description:
Faulting application name: BrassConsoleApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x60c2722d
Faulting module name: mso20win32client.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x60a155a8
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x001d3a12
Faulting process id: 0x49a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d75e34f0fb2b15
Faulting application path: D:\BitCrafters\Dev\Brass\Next\BrassConsoleApp\bin\Debug\BrassConsoleApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll
Report Id: b2318536-61c1-4958-85c0-a6803c4bbd3b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-06-10T20:30:01.9117979Z" />
    <EventRecordID>200410</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Dell5759</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>BrassConsoleApp.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>60c2722d</Data>
    <Data>mso20win32client.dll</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>60a155a8</Data>
    <Data>c000041d</Data>
    <Data>001d3a12</Data>
    <Data>49a8</Data>
    <Data>01d75e34f0fb2b15</Data>
    <Data>D:\BitCrafters\Dev\Brass\Next\BrassConsoleApp\bin\Debug\BrassConsoleApp.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll</Data>
    <Data>b2318536-61c1-4958-85c0-a6803c4bbd3b</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

SECOND EVENT VIEWER INFO LOG ENTRY JUST AFTER THE ONE ABOVE ---------------------------------------------------

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Windows Error Reporting
Date:          2021-Jun-10 4:30:04 PM
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Dell5759
Description:
Fault bucket 1496835596276001519, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: BrassConsoleApp.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 60c2722d
P4: mso20win32client.dll
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 60a155a8
P7: c000041d
P8: 001d3a12
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\TMP\{348A1C8B-8F9A-4947-A735-1A6662FAB73B} - OProcSessId.dat
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBA96.tmp.dmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBD95.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBDC5.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBDD3.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBE22.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_BrassConsoleApp._a65121a9886cf85d89cc2caea488de84ebbc6379_15a45da1_128d96b7-c591-43c7-8393-71b1b078c790

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: b2318536-61c1-4958-85c0-a6803c4bbd3b
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: e03e080836cae1e184c5d40b5330eaef
Cab Guid: 0
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-06-10T20:30:04.9119743Z" />
    <EventRecordID>200411</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Dell5759</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>1496835596276001519</Data>
    <Data>1</Data>
    <Data>APPCRASH</Data>
    <Data>Not available</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>BrassConsoleApp.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>60c2722d</Data>
    <Data>mso20win32client.dll</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>60a155a8</Data>
    <Data>c000041d</Data>
    <Data>001d3a12</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
\\?\C:\TMP\{348A1C8B-8F9A-4947-A735-1A6662FAB73B} - OProcSessId.dat
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBA96.tmp.dmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBD95.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBDC5.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBDD3.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERBE22.tmp.txt</Data>
    <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_BrassConsoleApp._a65121a9886cf85d89cc2caea488de84ebbc6379_15a45da1_128d96b7-c591-43c7-8393-71b1b078c790</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>b2318536-61c1-4958-85c0-a6803c4bbd3b</Data>
    <Data>268435456</Data>
    <Data>e03e080836cae1e184c5d40b5330eaef</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple approaches and dealing with this for over a week, I have decided to restructure my Service by replacing 3 timers with one. The single timer checks the time of day and calls the appropriate process.
I put this question up with the hope that someone would have the knowledge to decipher the Event Log entries. Since I did not get any response, I needed to move on with a solution.
Thank you for those of you that have taken a look and please disregard my original question as I have moved on.